# How to keep specific URL parameters on links?

Tags: php

I have the following URL:

```
http://website.com/?utm_source=1&utm_campaign=2&utm_medium=3
```

When a user access my website with these parameters, all links on my pages get the parameters and merge with their original URL.

So if a link is:

```
http://website.com/link.html
```

It will become:

```
http://website.com/link.html?utm_source=1&utm_campaign=2&utm_medium=3
```

But my Google Analytics is going nuts with so much data. And I only need to keep `utm_campaign`.

Is that possible to get only the value of `utm_campaign` and apply on my URL even if I have others parameters?

Here is my current code:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['utm_campaign']) {
    $queryURL = "?" . preg_replace("/(s=[a-zA-Z%+0-9]*&)(.*)/", "$2", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], -1);
    $queryURL = preg_replace("/q=([a-z0-9A-Z-\/])+&(.*)/", "$2", $queryURL, -1);
    $GLOBALS["queryURL"] = $queryURL;
} else {
    $GLOBALS["queryURL"] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Work with the `$_GET` array rather than the query string:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['utm_campaign'])) {
    $query_string = '?utm_campaign=' . $_REQUEST['utm_campaign'];
} else {
    $query_string = '';
}
```

Then when you create other links, you concatenate `$query_string` to them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible:

```
if (isset($_GET['utm_campaign'])) {
  $newUrl = $oldUrl.(strpos($oldUrl,'?') ? '&' : '?').'utm_campaign='.$_GET['utm_campaign'];
}
```

This piece of code will change the old url to a new url. It takes any parameters of the old url into account. I use `$_GET` because you don't need `$_POST` which is also in `$_REQUEST`.